# Serverless start not creating local DynamoDB database from yaml file

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

Im new to AWS. I far as i read, to create tables on start we need `migrate: true` under `custom.dynamodb` in yaml file. I have written serverless.yml file as follows.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  profile: default
  region: us-east-1
  memorySize: 512
  target: 'node' # Below defined environment variables wont be accessible in lambda functions.
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    USERS_TABLE: Users_${self:provider.stage}
    DAILYACTIVITY_TABLE: DailyActivity_${self:provider.stage}
  plugins:
    - serverless-dynamodb-local
    - serverless-offline
  custom:
    dynamodb:
      start:
        migrate: true
  resources:
    Resources:
      usersTable:
        Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
        DeletionPolicy: Retain
        Properties:
          AttributeDefinitions:
            - AttributeName: emailid
              AttributeType: S
            - AttributeName: id
              AttributeType: S
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: emailid
              KeyType: HASH
          GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
            - IndexName: gsi_id
              KeySchema:
                - AttributeName: id
                  KeyType: HASH
              ProvisionedThroughput:
                ReadCapacityUnits: 5
                WriteCapacityUnits: 5
              Projection:
                ProjectionType: ALL
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
          TableName: ${self:provider.environment.USERS_TABLE}
      activityTable:
        Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
        DeletionPolicy: Retain
        Properties:
          AttributeDefinitions:
            - AttributeName: id
              AttributeType: S
            - AttributeName: date
              AttributeType: S
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: id
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: date
              KeyType: RANGE
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
          TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DAILYACTIVITY_TABLE}
```

But `sls offline start` does not create tables from resources section.
Please suggest what is wrong with the above config.

Comment: Not sure if it would be related, but I had to change the version of serverless-dynamodb-local to 0.2.30 due to a different bug.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Assuming you already ran `sls dynamodb install`.
* `sls dynamodb uninstall`
*`npm uninstall 'your current version'`

*`npm install -D serverless-dynamodb-local@0.2.30`
*`sls dynamodb install`

Comment: yes, i did. Right now, i'm creating all the tables with separate script.
cause sls is not creating tables by itself from serverless.yml file

Comment: @pritesh did you manage to solve this? Because I am facing the same problem

Comment: @SalmanHasratKhan i did not get a command to create from yaml file but i wrote a script to create tables from the structure i defined using json. But that script is db script, not a sls script or command.

Comment: @pritesh I found the issue because I faced it too. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because all your keys, custom, plugins, resources are nested under provider. All these should be on the top level (indent level 0) in the yaml. I ran into the same problem and that's why it was not working. Also, please use serverless-local-dynamodb version 0.2.30. The latest (0.2.36) has issues.

I've reformatted the yaml for you so that you see what I mean

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  profile: default
  region: us-east-1
  memorySize: 512
  target: 'node' # Below defined environment variables wont be accessible in lambda functions.
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    USERS_TABLE: Users_${self:provider.stage}
    DAILYACTIVITY_TABLE: DailyActivity_${self:provider.stage}

plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  dynamodb:
    start:
      migrate: true

resources:
  Resources:
    usersTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: emailid
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: emailid
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: gsi_id
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: id
                KeyType: HASH
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 5
              WriteCapacityUnits: 5
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.USERS_TABLE}
    activityTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: date
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: date
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DAILYACTIVITY_TABLE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb cannot create two tables at the same time therefore you need to declare one as dependent on the other so that they are created in sequence and not in parallel.

```
"mySecondDDBTable" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
  "DependsOn" : "myFirstDDBTable" ,
  "Properties" : {
   ... etc
```

Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html specifically the section "DynamoDB Table with a DependsOn Attribute"